# mongoose cast to ObjectId failed for value error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I am facing this issue.
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "featured" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"

My router code is: -

```
router.get("/featured", async (req, res) => {
  const featuredProductsList = await Product.find({isProductFeatured: true})
  if(!featuredProductsList){
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Unable to fetch featured products"
    })
  }
  res.send(featuredProductsList)
})
```

and my product model codes are: -

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    productName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    productDescription: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    productRichDescription: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
    },
    productImage: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
    },
    productImages: [
        {
            type: String,
        },
    ],
    productBrand: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
    },
    productPrice: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
    },
    productCategory: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Category",
        require: true,
    },
    productCountStock: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
    },
    productRating: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
    },
    productNumberOfReviews: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
    },
    isProductFeatured: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    dateCreated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
});

const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema)

module.exports = {Product}
```

I am trying to fetch only those products which are isFeatured: true but I am getting this error. How to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but I met this error today and while searching saw your question, I just solved it by changing the route from /something ex: /featured to /details/featured because the /featured somehow is colliding with other routes like /:id